# Spring Cloud Vault. Issue with VaultPropertySource in environments without Vault

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-vault-config

I have a configuration class with `VaultPropertySource` annotation similar to the following that works great in environments that have access to Vault.

```
@Configuration  
@VaultPropertySource("secret/my-application")
public class AppConfig {

    @Value(${redis.password:default})
    private String password
}
```

The issue is that some deployments will not have access to Vault.  In my `bootstrap.yml` I have set `spring.cloud.vault.enabled = false` but I get

> Application failed to start - A component required a been named 'vaultTemplate' that could not be found.

At this point, I can comment out the `VaultPropertySource` and it works.  What can I do in these environments without Vault without having to comment out `VaultPropertySource`?

Answer (score 2):

Use [Spring profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html) to conditionally enable aspects such as Vault in your application. You can disable Vault by default in `bootstrap.yml` and re-enable it by having another config (e.g. `bootstrap-vault.yml`) that enables the Vault integration.

Applying the same pattern to `AppConfig` by using `@Profile(…)` would conditionally apply `@VaultPropertySource` and remove the need to provide `VaultTemplate`

```
@Configuration  
@VaultPropertySource("secret/my-application")
@Profile("vault")
public class AppConfig {

    @Value(${redis.password:default})
    private String password
}
```